# C# properties - Adding logic in the setter accessor

Tags: c#, if-statement, properties, set

I am trying to set the value of the property so if the account goes into debit there is a fee of 10 is charged. I've tried coding the property CurrentBalance in a number of ways including debit(10), value -10 and accountbalance-10 but none of these approaches work. The code compiles but does not charge a fee. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public void Credit(decimal amount)
    {
        accountBalance += amount; //add to balance
    }

    public void Debit(decimal amount)
    {
        accountBalance -= amount; //subtract amount
    }

    public decimal CurrentBalance
    {
        get
        {
            return accountBalance;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0) // if less than zero debit account by 10
            {
              value = accountBalance -10; // charge account
            }
            accountBalance = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this belongs into a setter function at all...

Comment: @ThiefMaster, I think it depends. This may be the business layer of the application and in that case I see no wrong in having it there

Comment: I've tried the examples in the responses below and it doesn't work well inside the setter.

Comment: I think it's because you never call the setter by setting the value of the property.  You're directly accessing the value of the field in the two functions you posted.  If you're using the setter elsewhere, you should post that code as well.

Comment: Usually one expects that `get` returns the same value that has been set by an immediately preceding `set`. Prefer a method if it doesn't. I would even change its name to `DebitWithFee`, thus making the "hidden" behavior obvious. A property should feel like a field.

Comment: Good advice Olivier about how a property should feel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be a better way to accomplish what you want:

```
public void Credit(decimal amount)
{
    accountBalance += amount; //add to balance
}

public void Debit(decimal amount)
{
    accountBalance -= amount; //subtract amount
    if(accountBalance < 0)
    {
        accountBalance -= 10;
    }
}

//make this a readonly property and use the debit and credit functions to adjust it
public decimal CurrentBalance
{
    get
    {
        return accountBalance;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does work, thank you. Though I was trying to test the functionality of get, set in an exercise book.

Comment: @Dave B: Could it be that you're not actually calling your setter?  I don't see you doing so in the code you posted in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it by changing your code to

```
set
{
    if (value < 0) // if less than zero debit account by 10
    {
        accountBalance = value -10; // charge account
    } else {
        accountBalance = value;
    }
}
```

However, it is not a good idea to do it in a setter that supplies the new value, because the current `accountBalance` gets discarded. it's better to do it in a function that adjusts the *current* value, like this:

```
public decimal AdjustBy(decimal amount) {
    accountBalance += amount;
    if (accountBalance < 0 && amount < 0) {
        // Charge fees on withdrawals when the resultant balance is < 0
        accountBalance -= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of that function?

Comment: This doesn't work either. I'm not sure if it is the logic in the main program but it works fine with credit and debit. I can see why a function would work better.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you are **never using the setter** (at least in the code snippets you posted).  In your `Debit` and `Credit` functions, you are setting the value of the underlying field (`accountBalance`), not the property (`CurrentBalance`).  For example, if you were to udate your `Debit` function like so, it would use the property's setter, and thus, charge a fee:

```
public void Debit(decimal amount)
{
    CurrentBalance -= amount; //subtract amount
}
```

**If you will always interact with the balance through either your `Debit` or `Credit` functions**, then I agree with the recommendation that you simply put the fee logic in the `Debit` function, rather than in a setter like so:

```
public void Debit(decimal amount)
{
    accountBalance -= amount; //subtract amount
    if(accountBalance < 0)
    {
        accountBalance -= 10; // Charge "overdraft" fee
    }
}
```

If you do that, you should make your property read-only so that it doesn't get inadvertently used by someone down the road (and thus bypassing your fee logic).  You can do that by simply not declaring a setter for your property.

On the other hand, **if you have many places in your code that adjust the balance without using these functions**, I'd recommend making `accountBalance` be a `private` field (if it isn't already) and then setting the value of `CurrentBalance` instead of `accountBalance` in your code like so:

```
CurrentBalance += amount; // add an amount
CurrentBalance -= amount; // subtract an amount
```

Comment: Jon, thanks for the clear explanation. Interacting through functions seems like the way that I could best control the logic given my grasp of the language. Accessing private fields does seem like the strength of using a property to me.